# Search and delete .Trash

Tags: shell, command-line, find

I have 4 large USB devices with lots of backups collected over the years.

I want to search for all .Trash folders and delete the contents on Fedora 17.  I tried the following which failed:-

```
    # find . -name ".Trash*"-exec rm -rf {} \;
    find: paths must precede expression: rm
    Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @rkosegi's answer:

```
 # find . -depth -name ".Trash*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Use `-depth` so that `find` doesn't try to descend the now deleted directory.

Comment: Or use `-delete`, which will automatically avoid this.

Answer (score 4):

You missed space between name pattern and exec parameter:

This:

```
 # find . -name ".Trash*"-exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Should be

```
 # find . -name ".Trash*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```